# React JS Apache FreeBSD build PUBLIC_URL Error

Tags: apache, reactjs, freebsd

Hi we created a new FreeBSD Server for testing, we created a react app that actually works in Ubuntu very well.

But on FreeBSD we have this error on the browser:

```
%PUBLIC_URL%/css/particles.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

We got the same config on Ubuntu but in that server it works:

Our apache config(FreeBSD):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName our_domain

        ServerAdmin our_email
        DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/apache24/data/react_frontend/public/
        <Directory /usr/local/www/apache24/data/react_frontend/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        # ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_impala.log
        # CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_impala.log combined
        # RewriteEngine On
        # RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
        # RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

What we are missing?

Regards.

Comment: How do you include your css files? Regular `<link>` tag in head? Try importing it in js file like: `import './particles.css';`

Comment: Hi, on public/index.html
    `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/particles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/rodal.css">`

Comment: In case you would like to use nginx: https://medium.com/@johnbrett/create-react-app-push-state-nginx-config-a9f7530621c1